# Nginx HTTP Error 404 Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set a reverse proxy using Nginx to serve static files to my webapp within a container but am failing miserably... The problem is that Nginx is serving static files just fine when I go into the django admin page, but once I try to go to an endpoint using rest framework I get hit by a "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found." error.

Here is how I have things set up:

My Nginx setting:

```
upstream django {
    server store:27036;
}

server {

    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }
    

}
```

My docker-compose setting:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  store:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "27036:27036"

    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: my_app.settings.prod
      STORE_HOST: ${STORE_HOST}
      STORE_PORT: ${STORE_PORT}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${STORE_DB_NAME}
      DATABASE_HOST: ${STORE_DB_HOST}
      DATABASE_USER: ${STORE_DB_USER}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${STORE_DB_PASSWORD}
      SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
      ALLOWED_HOSTS: ${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
    platform: "linux/amd64"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - store_data:/app
      # - static:/static
      - static_data:/vol/web

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    cap_add:
        # suppress log messages from cluttering the shell output
      - SYS_NICE
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --mysqlx=0
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: ${STORE_DB_HOST}
      MYSQL_PORT: ${STORE_DB_PORT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${STORE_DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${STORE_DB_PASSWORD}
    platform: "linux/amd64"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      # - static:/static
      - static_data:/vol/static
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - store   
  
volumes:
  # static:
  static_data:
  mysqldata:
  store_data:
```

I have no clue what am doing wrong exactly or why the error only occurs when I try access an endpoint in the api.
Worth mentioning that am using windows

**EDIT**: I think I found the answer but I also found a new smaller issue. Hopefully the new issue has a much simpler solution so am hoping someone can help.

**The following are screenshots of my API root.
The first one am not using the reverse proxy server:**
[image: No Proxy being used here]

Now this is the same API root with the **reverse proxy**:
[image: Root with Reverse Proxy]

You will notice that while using the proxy, the URL don't contain the port number for whatever reason. So I figured that if I manually added them it should work. And it did...

The new problem is the fact that I don't know how to get the proxy to be something like: **127:0.0.1:8080** instead of **127:0.0.1**.

And am sorry if my explanation seems clumsy but I am very new to docker and Nginx. Just hope you understand and thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding turning on the autoindex for your nginx and adding a try_files clause, I don't know if that would be of any help. please let me know

Comment: I will attempt that. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

After your final edit to the question now the answer would be that you might add the port to your `proxy_pass` in your Nginx configuration file .. also just expose the port you want the Nginx to communicate with Django on the first service of your docker-compose.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  django:
    build:
      context: .
    expose:
      - "27036"

    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: my_app.settings.prod
      STORE_HOST: ${STORE_HOST}
      STORE_PORT: ${STORE_PORT}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${STORE_DB_NAME}
      DATABASE_HOST: ${STORE_DB_HOST}
      DATABASE_USER: ${STORE_DB_USER}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${STORE_DB_PASSWORD}
      SECRET_KEY: ${SECRET_KEY}
      ALLOWED_HOSTS: ${ALLOWED_HOSTS}
    platform: "linux/amd64"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - store_data:/app
      # - static:/static
      - static_data:/vol/web

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    cap_add:
        # suppress log messages from cluttering the shell output
      - SYS_NICE
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --mysqlx=0
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: ${STORE_DB_HOST}
      MYSQL_PORT: ${STORE_DB_PORT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${STORE_DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${STORE_DB_PASSWORD}
    platform: "linux/amd64"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      # - static:/static
      - static_data:/vol/static
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - store   
  
  volumes:
    # static:
    static_data:
    mysqldata:
    store_data:
```

---

default.conf:

```
server {

    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:27036;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }
    

}
```

you can find an example of that in here https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

This works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get hit with the error:  upstream "django" may not have port 8080 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:10

Comment: please check the new answer, hope it works

Comment: Hi again there. First of all thank you so much for trying to help. This approach didnt work either but it did help me realize something: Typing localhost or 127.0.0.1 on the url search bar generates the exact same error even without nginx being active so I assume the problem lies elsewhere. I will post a new question in regards to the particular issue I just mentioned

Comment: Hi again. I managed to sort the issue out by debugging whatever was causing localhost and 127.0.0.1 to trigger an error. In the end there was nothing particularly wrong with the ngnix config or the docker compose but I did adjust the part where you stated I had to only expose port 27036. At any rate, thank you for your time and help!